# Set focus of button to be the button that replaces it when selected via keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, angular, accessibility

Working on the accessibility for a form, specifically navigating via keyboard. There is one button called `add skill` and another called `remove skill`. When the `add skill` button is pressed, the `remove skill` button replaces it, so they don't both sit on the screen at the same time.

Currently, the focus of the button does not automatically move from one button to the other, instead it jumps to a div before or after the button depending on what button has been selected.

What I've tried so far is to add some JavaScript to focus `onclick` to the other button, I can get it working from when two buttons are on the screen at the same time but not so much for dynamic buttons.

I'd like to change this so the focus changes onto the button that has dynamically appeared.

Here is the code:

````
<button *ngIf="updateable && isSelected()"
    class="float-right ui inverted button" tabindex="0">
    Remove
    <span class="screen-reader-only">
        {{ skill.name }}
    </span>
    skill
</button>
<button *ngIf="updateable && !isSelected()" [class.disabled]="selectDisabled()" class="float-right ui button"
     tabindex="0" >
    Add
    <span class="screen-reader-only">
        {{ skill.name }}
    </span>
    skill
</button>```

Any help would be much appreciated!
````

Comment: (Probably not what you wanted to hear, but - IMHO having these buttons “switch places”, is an accessibility issue in and of itself already. The problems this might cause for certain users, are likely not going to be fixed by manipulating where the focus jumps to.)

Comment: u need to call .focus() on the element which appeared, may be u r calling, but by that time the element is not there in DOM.

Comment: @CBroe I think you are right to highlight this issue and I would've saved a lot of time messing about with things if they where both present on the page to begin with!

Comment: @CBroe Do you have any documentation to support your assertion? I'd love to be able to change the design on this and I think that discussion would better for me if I can provide some evidence.